# given up on gridview fixed header

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, visual-studio-2008, gridview

Working on: asp.net Gridview Control
ok i tried and tried and maybe searched the entire web... but i could not find anything good for my asp.net gridviewcontrolwhich whill fix the header and allow sorting. but most of all work in all browsers and not just IE and Firefox alone.... chrome was the main problem nothing worked...

this was one option:

```
.HeaderFreez
{
position:relative ;
top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
 z-index: 10;
}
```

but here i first get an error that "expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);" not valid in top. even if this worked it work on all browsers.

then there was this link:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=255

but it only worked for IE and Firefox and that too not for IE 8.

then there were examples where the pseudo headers were created at fixed location but i have so many gridviews in my project that the alignment go haywire... also when did this got 2 headers in chrome... funny..

like the one here...
http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2008/03/fixed-header-in-gridview-cross-browser.html

so now im giving up.. if any one knows anything better... or thinks i am going wrong somewhere please help...

thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is an option for you, but [Telerik's Grid control](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) allows for a fixed header, works great in all browsers, and is extremely feature-rich in case you need to do grouping or multi-selection or anything of that nature.

Again, maybe not a viable option if your shop doesn't have $800-$1000 to throw around for 3rd party tools, but from my experience, you won't be disappointed with Telerik's set!

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS Editor of Visual Studio 2005, the expression(offsetParent.scrollTop) will be treated as a invalid value, and will show this invalid values in the Error List.

You can configure the Visual Studio 2005 not to show this error by Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> CSS -> CSS Specific -> Uncheck "Detect invalid values".